# Javascript fallback for fusionmaps

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I could get FusionCharts XT to work in iPad by setting it to render in JavaScript. But I could not get FusionMaps working in iPad.

Is FusionMaps JavaScript fallback supported?

Answer (score 1):

Currently FusionMaps does not have JavaScript fallback. You can check back again in a quarter's time for the updates.